# How do I access that basic command line tutorial man document?

Tags: manpage

I need to find that documentation that acts like a simple description and tutorial of how the command line works. It's "man *something*" I knw that much, so it's a man page, but not an actual command. It mentions the "find" command having a baroque syntax, I remember that. How do I find this page?

Comment: You could have tried asking to the man himself: `man man`. Scroll slightly and `man -a intro` is one of the examples with a description of what it does.

Comment: You may be interested in [*Introduction to Linux*](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/) by Machtelt Garrels, available on the [Linux Documentation Project](https://www.tldp.org/) website.

Answer (score 33):

You are looking for the `man intro`. Just type

```
man intro
```

This will open the first `man intro` section, the one that you are (I will stab a guess) most likely interested in. To view all `man intro` sections type

```
man -a intro
```

and you will be prompted to view them all, unless you decide to quit.

Comment: @Graham OP can't upvote the answer, not enough reputation, but he can mark the answer as **ACCEPTED**, notably for people which will find this topic on Google for example

Answer (score 5):

`man intro` is the right answer here.  But to be a bit more general, if you want to search *all* manpages for particular keywords, you can use `man -wK`.

In particular, you knew that the page you were looking for contained the word "baroque", which is a nice specific search term:

```
$ man -wK baroque
/usr/share/man/man1/intro.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/zshmodules.1.gz
$
```

If you want to jump directly to the manpages in the results, in turn, simply use `man -K` instead.

Note that the `-K` option is a brute-force search through all manpages, so can take some time.  In my case it takes 20-25 seconds on my Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Note that `man -K` "is a brute-force search, and is likely to take some time; if  you  can, you  should  specify a section to reduce the number of pages that need to be searched." For example: `man -S 1 -K  baroque` (section 1 - user commands) takes less than a third of the time than without specifying the section. If you know a keyword in the _description_ of a page you can use `man -k KEYWORD` (lower case "k") which can also be run as `apropos KEYWORD` (e.g. `apropos introduction`) which will be faster still.